# Install teamviewer in debian jessie (amd64) from command line

Tags: debian, teamviewer

So, I am trying to install teamviewer in a server from putty. The server is Debian 8.3. I downloaded the right version of teamviewer and sent it at the server via filezilla. When trying to install it with `dpkg -i teamviewer_filename` it says missing dependencies.

I installed two of the 4 required packages, but when it comes to **lib32asound2** and **ia32-libs** it says that **ia32-libs**  is not available but can be replaced by lib32ncurses5 (which i did install afterwards, I don't know if it solved the problem).

As of **lib32asound2** it says

[image]

I removed the Debian installation so far since it was incomplete anyway, but don't know how to proceed. I am searching for alternative searches to get the packages, but the versions found are of earlier releases (Debian wheezy). Could you give me some hint of what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dowload `teamviewer_11.0.53191_i386.deb`

Then run the following command :

```
   apt-get install -f
```

and execute the following command lines as an root:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

install

```
dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.53191_i386.deb
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue on my machine.

Comment: @AdrianKeister welcome , It is better to ask a new question and give some details